# Zfcuser Example - Integrating in real application

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I've been unable to find any example of how actually to use zfcuser to authenticate users and prevent access to a website or routes.

My website successfully works when I access /user/login, but this is useless in a real application.
What I really need is:

1) If user is not logged in to the website, it needs to be forwarded to the login page

2) Attempting to access pages on any route will display the login page

How do I do this in my modules?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the wiki. It tells you how to check if the user is authenticated, both in view and controller.

Also for access control, take a look at the following modules: BjyAuthorize, ZfcRbac, Eye4webAbac